# check the variable name present in table? or not

Tags: php

I want to check that if the value whch is coming from post `$var` is present in table or not if yes then give me message existed n exit. If not then insert into the table

```
$qry    = "SELECT * FROM  nl_lang_var where name='$var'";
$res =$GLOBALS['DB']->execute($qry);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)> 0)
        {
            echo "already existed";
            exit;}
            else {
                     $sql = "INSERT INTO  nl_lang_var set value='$value' , name='$var' and langid=$langid"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

user INSERT IGNORE in mysql [Ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable
    (primaryKey, field1, field2)
VALUES
    ('abc', 1, 2);
```